# Automating data in autocad using VBA

Tags: vba, autocad

I have a drawing file in autocad dwg format which shows trees and their tree number in text. now i want to create a excel file having details of tree number and their coordinates. Till now i have achieved looping through the tree object and then user has to input the tree number. Can this process be automated using the proximity calculation i.e. the code search for nearest text and then attaches the tree number from the text to the tree on excel sheet.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SelectionSet to select texts inside tree. More You can see for example here.

https://www.engram9.info/autocad-2006-vba/selecting-entities.html

It would be something like:

```
Dim p1 As Variant
Dim p2 As Variant

tree.GetBoundingBox p1, p2

Set objSS = ThisDrawing.SelectionSets.Add("TestSelectSS")
objSS.Select acSelectionSetWindow, p1 , p2
```

Be carefull please. It's just writen by hand, I don't even know if it will run, but just want to point You direction.
Then You need to iterate through objSS , and get text You want. You may also use SelectionSet filters, so `objSS.Select` will return only texts.